# How to deal with users like this?

Tags: support, moderation

This user is really annoying: https://askubuntu.com/users/251046/user251046?tab=answers
Is there any preferred way to deal with users like this, besides flagging the answers?

Comment: Nope. Just flag a couple answers, or if it's a trend (like here) use a custom reason and explain what's going on.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I just recently started participating in moderation and weren't sure if I should do so as I didn't want to cause the mods unnecessary work.

Comment: They do not seem to work I have a pair of users that down flag or make un necessary comments on my questions and comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flag and vote accordingly. We have mechanisms set in place so the abusive users don't poison the system.